# Asp.net How to make the 'link text' from a 'search bar' href configurable

Tags: asp.net

I would like to be able to use an 'AppSettings' key in Web.config to assign a value to the href 'link text'.

So, in the below sample code, I would like to make `*Add Order*` configurable.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li class="searchBar">
    <input id="searchBox" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Order #" onkeypress="quickSearch(event);">
</li>
<li><a href="ManageOrder.aspx">Manage Order</a></li>
<li><a href="AddOrderForm.aspx">*Add Order*</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="DashBoard.aspx">DashBoard</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the solution I settled on:

```
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="AddOrderButton" runat="server" CssClass="form-group"
        NavigateUrl="AddOrderForm.aspx" Text="<%$ Appsettings:AddOrderButton %>">
    </asp:HyperLink> </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this code to read from the config file and use the value. Firstly you need to make sure to import the namespace at the top of your file:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>
```

Then read from it and use it:

```
<a href="AddOrderForm.aspx"><%= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourKey"] %></a>
```

Comment: The namespace reference is for the code page (.cs). How can I use 'WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings' on the web page (menu.ascx)?

Comment: You can put the namepace in the aspx page.

Comment: This is the solution I settled on:  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="AddButton" runat="server" CssClass="form-group"
            NavigateUrl="AddOrderForm.aspx" Text="<%$ Appsettings:AddButton %>">
        </asp:HyperLink> </li>

Comment: I gave you the whole code. What seems to be the issue? What is `$Appsettings:AddButton`? The code in my answer needs to be placed in your `aspx` page.

Comment: I made an edit to help you with importing the namespace.

Comment: I put my solution above. I give you credit in that you pointed me the the right direction - thanks! edit: Ah - I see the updated reference now - thanks!